# echo entire file in php and send to jquery

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-forms-plugin

I'm using the JQuery Form Plugin to upload a file. I am able to send the contents of an uploaded txt file to the jquery associated with the form plugin but I want to send the entire file.

Right now I echo the variable $c in my php and this is sent to my jquery. Can I somehow send the entire file with $file?

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');

foreach($_FILES as $file) {
    $n = $file['name'];
    $s = $file['size'];
$t = $file["tmp_name"];
$c= file_get_contents($t);


    if (is_array($n)) {
        $c = count($n);
        for ($i=0; $i < $c; $i++) {
            //echo "<br>uploaded: " . $n[$i] . " (" . $s[$i] . " bytes)";

        }
    }
    else {
        //echo "<br>uploaded: $n ($s bytes)";
    }
 //echo "<br>uploaded: $n ($s bytes)";
}

echo $c;

?>
```

Then in my jquery from the jquery form plugin:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    (function() {

    var bar = $('.bar');
    var percent = $('.percent');
    var status = $('#status');

    $('#dataform').ajaxForm({
        beforeSend: function() {
            status.empty();
            var percentVal = '0%';
            bar.width(percentVal)
            percent.html(percentVal);
        },
        uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
            var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
            bar.width(percentVal)
            percent.html(percentVal);
        },
        success: function(data, responseText, statusText, $form) {
            var percentVal = '100%';
            bar.width(percentVal)
            percent.html(percentVal);

            $.post('/submit', {name: data}, function(data) {
                $('body').append(data);
                });

        },
    complete: function(xhr) {
        status.html(xhr.responseText);
    }
    //
    }); 
    return false;
    })();       

});
```

Answer (score 1):

you just have to keep one thing in mind, the ajax request will read the output sent by the server, that's why it reads only the `echo`ed statement, just decide what you want to send and send it as plain text or whatever form you like, if you want to get the file, there might be a problem because the server will try to execute the content if it's a `php` file, but there is an easy hack, rename the extension of the file to something like `txt` and the server will send it as is, it's your decision to make.

Answer (score 1):

Sending the contents of a file is equivalent to sending the file. The question is, why do you want to do what you are asking. If you want to spare the file handling on the server side, then I'm afraid this is just the way to do it.